# Pylance: "ClassVar" is not allowed in this context?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

With the following function:

```py
from typing import ClassVar 

def overrode_make_stub(cls: ClassVar["Emailer"]) -> bool:
    return not (getattr(cls.make_stub, "_not_overridden", False))
```

I’m getting this error from Pylance in Visual Studio Code:

> "ClassVar" is not allowed in this context

I’m using Python3.9 and Pylance v2021.10.0.

In this example the `Email` class has a "make_stub" function, which has a `_not_overriden` attribute set to `True`. When I inspect a module for subclasses of that class I can use this to filter only the ones that overrode the "make_sub" function.

I can’t find any documentation on this error. Does anyone know why it’s coming up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ClassVar` type hint is intended to mark class-level variables to tell the type system that they really are class variables, not defaults for instance variables.

```
from typing import ClassVar

class Example:
    x: int              # x and y are being type hinted as instance variables
    y: int
    z: ClassVar[int]    # z is being type hinted as a class variable instead
```

If the argument to your function is supposed to be a class, then [you should use `typing.Type`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects) as the type hint. Try this, to hint that you expect a subclass of `Emailer`:

```
from typing import Type

def overrode_make_stub(cls: Type["Emailer"]) -> bool:
    return not (getattr(cls.make_stub, "_not_overridden", False))
```

Note that if you only need to be compatible with Python 3.9 and later, you don't actually need to use `typing.Type` at all. You can instead use the builtin `type` object, which can be indexed in the same way, thanks to [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/): `cls: type["Emailer"]`